# Hourglass figure and how to prevent it

Tags: abdominals, exercise-technique

I just started working out and have noticed that I am developing a sort of hourglass figure. I have some understanding that this might have to do with underdeveloped obliques and some other muscles. I was wondering if someone could shed light on the issue and how to prevent it. (picture for reference, that's not me btw)

[image]

Below is the kind of abs i would like to work towards .
https://twitter.com/attractiveeguys/status/1019302159098269699

Comment: The biggest difference between the photos you are comparing is... lighting and angle. Both have very similar ab / torso shapes.

Answer (score 5):

This probably isn't the answer you want, but it looks like this is an issue with angles and body fat.

TLDR: It probably isn't something to worry about. A cinched in waist means you're lean with broad shoulders.

With the image you posted, the model has considerably low body fat, he's flexing and leaning forward so his waist tucks in and his hip bones protrude out. He may also genetically carry his body fat in his lower abdominals which will contribute to the look. In addition, the camera is level to his torso and is facing straight on, so it's easier to see. It would be less noticeable if the model was twisted to the side.

In the image from the Twitter page, the bodyfat is slightly higher and more evenly spread out, and he's relaxed so the waist is less cinched. The camera is also facing at an angle and down. You can still see he still has the "hourglass" figure although it's more difficult to tell.

You can see that even people with very well developed obliques can still have this figure (some more than others):

[image]
[image]
[image]

People who carry more bodyfat in their lower torso may look like they have more hips than they really do. Some men may also have slightly larger hips than others. Both of these would contribute to the "hourglass" shape. Both of these are genetics and you really can't do much about it. The former can be fixed by getting even leaner but it would probably be very difficult to sustain depending on how lean you have to get.

---

As far as angles and flexing, [it's surprising how much you can change your appearance](https://www.insider.com/bodybuilder-showed-how-fitness-photos-can-be-misleading-2019-10#murphy-has-also-found-that-positioning-the-camera-at-a-higher-angle-can-make-his-muscles-look-bigger-especially-if-hes-trying-to-emphasize-his-upper-body-5) in photos by simple tweaks. Particularly when you are pretty lean.  Some examples (from the link which could die)

[image]

[image]

[image]

So the takeaway from this would be, don't worry too much about it. It's normal. It just means you're lean. You simultaneously have it and don't have it depending on where you see yourself.